# How can I fill my dataframe with zeros n time s?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have this dataframe :

```
index  B  C  D
0      8  7  9
1      6  2  7
2      7  6  9
```

I would like to have this output:

```
index  B  C  D
0      8  7  9
1      6  2  7
2      7  6  9
...     ....
n-1    0  0  0
n      0  0  0
```

I tried but couldn't do it.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

If need add new rows filled by 0 values use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
N = 5
df = pd.concat(
    [df, pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(N), columns=df.columns)], 
    ignore_index=True
)
```

Or if there is default index use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
N = 5
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.max() + N + 1), fill_value=0)

>>> print(df)
   B  C  D
0  8  7  9
1  6  2  7
2  7  6  9
3  0  0  0
4  0  0  0
5  0  0  0
6  0  0  0
7  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the first answer that came to my mind, I hope it helps.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [8, 7, 9],
                   'C': [6, 2, 7],
                   'D': [7, 6, 9]})

zeros = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0],
                   'C': [0],
                   'D': [0]})

n = 10
for row in range(n):
    df = pd.concat([df, zeros], axis=0)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a zeros matrix with numpy

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((N_rows, N_cols)))
```

and use `pd.concat()` to merge the dataframes

```
df = pd.concat([df, d], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a Pandas DataFrame `df` you can expand it with `N` rows of 0. It seems best to use the numpy library.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"B": [8, 6, 7], "C": [7, 2, 6], "D": [9, 7, 9]})


def df_add_zero_rows(df: pd.DataFrame, N: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Adds N rows of 0 to any DataFrame

    :param df: DataFrame where 0-rows will be added
    :param N: No. 0-rows to add.

    :return: The given DataFrame with appended N 0-rows.
    """
    zero_rows = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((N, df.shape[0])), columns=df.columns)
    return pd.concat([df, zero_rows], ignore_index=True)
```

Using the function

```
>>> print(df_add_zero_rows(df, 5))

     B    C    D
0  8.0  7.0  9.0
1  6.0  2.0  7.0
2  7.0  6.0  9.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0
```